# How to use Restrict annotation and tag properly

Tags: java, seam, jaas

I would like to use @Restrict in seam application. One of my scenario contains a series of actions. Do i need to restrict each and every action or only the starting action? All the actions except first is invoked from first action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are private methods then you don't need to restrict them. 
However, if they are public methods, you should restrict them, because it is possible to call methods from the parameter.

If you annotate the `class` with the `@Restrict` annotation, then all the methods will be restricted.